# I have a block of code that works and I wanted to ask what exactly is happening here?

Tags: java, android

The semicolon (;) at the end of the code is the thing which is got me lost.

```
private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
        r.setName(name.getText().toString());
        r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());

    }
};
```

Comment: Why does it lost you? What is valid: `private String s = "foo"` or `private String s = "foo";`?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid ques.. It's just that I am a newbee trying to learn Java and android.. The explanation by T.J. Crowder helped.. Thanks for your reply too!

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. Anonymous inner classes look really weird when you first meet them. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is an instantiation of an instance of an anonymous inner class. The semicolon ends the assignment statement that assigns the new instance to `onSave`. It's basically shorthand for this:

```
private View.OnClickListener onSave = new MyClickListener();
//                                  the same semicolon ----^

// ...elsewhere, but inside your class...
private class MyClickListener extends View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
        r.setName(name.getText().toString());
        r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

What we have here is an anonymous inner class. Practically what happens is you are saying "I want to use an object **just this time** that extends `View.OnClickListener`". Then you provide the implementation of that object's type directly inline by specifying the `onClick` method code.

The entire code you posted is simply an assignment, which translates to:

```
A a = new SubclassOfA();
```

where `SubclassOfA` is defined inline directly.

Answer (score 2):

The semi colon at the end is the end of your onSave declaration.

Same as if you had:

```
String onSave = "hello"
;
```

Except the "hello" bit is replaced with a more complex structure!

Answer (score 2):

it is an instance of an an anonymous class. Hence the semicolon in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining an instance of `OnClickListener`. As this is the interface, you have to implement it's `onclick` method. Also this is the statement, therefore ";" must be used at the end.